# React Native Firebase Push Notification iOS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

im quite new in react native mobile developer. I have been working on push notifications with firebase. However, it works nice in android. Bu not working on ios simulator. Would you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal :

> FCM messages can be sent to real Android/iOS devices and Android
> emulators (iOS simulators however do not handle cloud messages)

https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#receiving-messages

Comment: but i tried in physical device iphone, it didnt work. what should i do?

Comment: Did you follow all steps from [iOS Messaging Setup](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup) ? 
Be careful, notification is not displayed when the app is in foreground

Comment: yes, i followed all steps. There is no background notification tho.